# Can I save a stream-only track locally for offline capability?

Tags: ios, soundcloud

I am developing an iOS app that will play music from soundcloud. I want to give the user the option of an offline mode so he/she can play music even if there is no connection available.

it is technically possible to download the streamed mp3:s locally (I have already implemented it) but will Soundcloud allow me to do it? I have no intention of making these mp3:s accessible outside the app.

The problem of using a downloaded copy instead of the streamed track would be that the play would not count. Is there a way to register a play without actually playing the track?

I have tried to reach them through mail and twitter but I have got no reply yet.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I cannot speak for the SoundCloud's legal department, but I can say that the content creators on SoundCloud have an option for making their tracks downloadable and we do our best to respect those who have disabled it. The [T&Cs](http://developers.soundcloud.com/policies) ask that you do not download the content. I'm sure that you do not intend to abuse the service, but it is still very important to us to protect the creators of the content, so this is expressly disallowed. Sorry to be the bad guy here, but I hope you understand. Please do ask if you'd like any more clarification.

Comment: While this was not the answer I was hoping for, I was pretty sure this was the case. Thank you NickF for taking time to reply.

Another question on the same topic, suppose I implemented some sort of cache or offline mode that did not use the offline versions of the tracks if the user is really offline. Each time the user is online, the streamed version would be used. If the user pulls his track from his page, then the offline version would of course be removed as soon as the user tries to play it while connected to the internet. Would this implementation be allowed?

Comment: I am but a lowly code monkey, and couldn't give you a proper answer for that, sorry. Your best bet is to send an email to api@soundcloud.com and someone should be able to give you a definitive answer there.

Comment: Also, if you're on the twitters: http://twitter.com/#!/soundcloudapi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short summary of nickf:s comment above: 
**this is expressly disallowed**